# Is there is a way to view an image/jpeg response in ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, httpurlconnection

I am calling a GET api and it returns a string of image/jpeg contentType, I am using urlConnection to proceed the request.
How to display the response in an ImageView ?
`GET https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg`
It returns weird string.

I have tried to save the response to a file and display it but it doesn’t success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party libraries to load and display images from `URL` ([Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Landscapist](https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist), [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)). They are easy to use and supports caching image out of the box.

If you are using jetpack compose, I would suggest using Landscapist as it has more features in compose. If not Glide and Coil are also OK.

Examples for loading images:

Glide:

```java
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Coil:

```kotlin
val imageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view) as ImageView;

imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
```

Landscapist:

```kotlin
// with glide
GlideImage(
  imageModel = { "https://www.example.com/image.jpg" },
  imageOptions = ImageOptions(
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    alignment = Alignment.Center
  )
)

// with coil
CoilImage(
  imageModel = { "https://www.example.com/image.jpg" },
  imageOptions = ImageOptions(
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    alignment = Alignment.Center
  )
)

// with fresco
FrescoImage(
  imageUrl = "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
  imageOptions = ImageOptions(
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    alignment = Alignment.Center
  )
)
```